# A custom layer, org-roam, only works on the 3rd restart of spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, package

I'm using Spacemacs v.0.200.13, and GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2019-09-16.

I'd like to install and use the [org-roam](https://github.com/jethrokuan/org-roam/) package.

The [instructions](https://org-roam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/) indicate that Spacemacs users should create a custom layer, use `use-package` to fetch the package using `recipe :fetcher github :repo (url)`.

I have done so.

**/home/me/.emacs.d/private/org-roam/packages.el**

```
(defconst org-roam-packages
  '((org-roam :location
              (recipe :fetcher github :repo "jethrokuan/org-roam" :branch "develop"))))

(defun org-roam/init-org-roam ()
  (use-package org-roam
    :after org
    :hook
    (after-init . org-roam-mode)
    :custom
    (org-roam-directory "~/Dropbox/org/notes")
    :init
    (progn
      (spacemacs/declare-prefix "ar" "org-roam")
      (spacemacs/set-leader-keys
        "arl" 'org-roam
        "art" 'org-roam-today
        "arf" 'org-roam-find-file
        "arg" 'org-roam-show-graph)

      (spacemacs/declare-prefix-for-mode 'org-mode "mr" "org-roam")
      (spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode 'org-mode
        "rl" 'org-roam
        "rt" 'org-roam-today
        "rb" 'org-roam-switch-to-buffer
        "rf" 'org-roam-find-file
        "ri" 'org-roam-insert
        "rg" 'org-roam-show-graph))))
```

Then, in my **.spacemacs**, I add the package to my `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`.

**.spacemacs**

```
   dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '(
     org-roam
     )
```

Now, if I restart emacs using `restart-emacs-resume-layouts`, and attempt to run any of the `org-roam` functions, I get the following error:

```
command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, org-roam-find-file
```

Looking through my messages, I see no obvious warnings or errors.

Then, I delete `org-roam` from my `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`. I `restart-emacs-resume-layouts`. I re-add `org-roam` to my ``dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`. Now, if I run any of the`org-roam`functions, they work. However, I get the infamous`SPC SPC is undefined`error, which I usually take to mean there's some kind of error in my`.spacemacs`. Again, though, nothing in`messages.` And, if I restart again, the functions again error.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/CGFaay8u) is my .spacemacs in its entirety.

If I do `describe-package` when spacemacs is in a state where any of the `org-roam` functions give the `commandp` error, I see:

```
org-roam is an installed package.

     Status: Installed in ‘org-roam-20200224.258/’ (unsigned). Delete
    Version: 20200224.258
    Summary: Roam Research replica with Org-mode
   Requires: emacs-26.1, dash-2.13, f-0.17.2, s-1.12.0, async-1.9.4, org-9.0
   Homepage: https://github.com/jethrokuan/org-roam
   Keywords: org-mode roam convenience
```

How can I successfully use `org-roam` while still maintaining my `SPC SPC` keybindings, and in a way where it persists across emacs restarts?

EDIT: If I delete the `org-roam` folder in `.emacs.d/elpa`, then restart emacs, I get into the state wherein `org-roam` functions work, but I get `SPC SPC is undefined` errors.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/dAYvhEB9) is my entire messages buffer after a restart into the state where org-roam functions work, but `SPC SPC` doesn't.

Comment: As a temporary solution, ensuring org-roam-mode is running can allow both `SPC SPC` as well as the usage of `org-roam` functions. See https://github.com/jethrokuan/org-roam/pull/133#issuecomment-591012743

Answer (score 1):

You might try and add this to the top of the packages file or in a `layers.el` file.

```
(configuration-layer/declare-layer 'org)
```

I placed this in a separate `layers.el` file since spacemacs will load that first.

This has worked for me but I can't get the shortcuts to work.

[Edit]

I also compared my config to yours. I'm using defer in the use-package init:

```
    (defun org-roam-layer/init-org-roam ()
  (use-package org-roam
    :after org
    :hook
    (after-init . org-roam-mode)
    :defer t
    :init 
    (progn
        ...
```

Comment: I tried both adding the configuration-layer setting to the top of the `packages.el` file as well as to a new `layers.el` file, neither seemed to solve the issue (though I did get SPC SPC back`.

Comment: With the line at the top of the `packages.el` file, the behavior is identical to before regarding resets. Adding the `:defer t` didn't seem to change anything either... though I appreciate your help.